# Blender Motion Blur deactivation for certain objects doesn´t work

Tags: cycles-render-engine, ocean-simulation, motion-blur

[image]if I have set Motion Blur for rendering and deactivate it for a certain object in the object properties, the object is still blurred. The scene is a tracking shot from behind towards a boat that is cruising on the water. Motion blur should only be used on the water. I would be very happy for any help! I use Cycles for Rendering.

Kind Regards,
Tim

Comment: It could be the camera's motion blur. If that is the case, you will likely need to render separate sequences and recombine them to totally kill the motion blur on one object.

Comment: Hmm I have a lot of scenes overall. And to render everything twice wouldn't be very nice. But is there no other solution or how else is it done normally? When filming in 24p there must always be a certain amount of motion blur inside.

Comment: We could probably figure out a better solution if you could provide some exemplary images to explain more precisely what you want to achieve along with the reasoning behind turning off motion blur for just one object. It's tricky to understand from a written explanation alone.

Comment: Yes gladly. I have now inserted a picture of the boat scene into the question of where the camera goes to the boat. Since the boat does not move much during the tracking shot in the image section, it should actually be sharp there and only the water should have a motion blur effect. Blender still makes the ship very blurry.

Answer (score 0):

### Vector Blur Solution

When using the *Vector* pass and the *Vector Blur* node, individual objects can easily be "unblurred" by mixing in the raw render which has no blur.

To enable the *Vector* pass, *Motion Blur* must be disabled.
[image: 1]

The *Vector* pass an be enabled in *Properties > View Layer Properties > Passes > Vector.*
[image]
I have also enabled *Object Index* for creating the object mask, but using *Cryptomatte* would work even better.

My boat proxy object has its *Pass Index* set to 1 for this mask.
[image: 3]

In the compositor, the object's mask can now be used to zero the *Vector* pass and mix in the raw render where necessary as seen in the node setup below.
[image: 4]
The *Dilate/Erode* node is used to reduce the color bleed artifacts from the *Vector Blur* node.

### Side-By-Side

[image: 5]
*my proxy scene with the blur removed on the right side of the arrow object*

Comment: Thanks for your answer HISEROD!
I had heard of this solution before, but the problem with me is that I sometimes have very complex scenes like in the jungle with a large number of objects. Applying that to all objects differently for each movement would be pretty horror. I had thought that Blender could do this very easily with the Motion Blur Option 
by recognizing how much the object moves in the image section and blurs it accordingly..

Comment: Will it be maybe useful to have a computer with RTX graphics cards for rendering?
-> [GPU-Accelerated Motion Blur in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i-JVcRbX9M)

Comment: I believe that the accelerated motion blur is only for the Eevee and Cycles motion blur, not for the compositor effect.

Comment: @Tim *Cryptomatte* should work really well for masking out many objects.

Comment: Ok thanks again. I'll take a closer look at that in the next few days 